# For what $\lambda$ is the channel $\mathcal E(\rho)=\lambda \rho^T + \frac{1-\lambda}{d}I$ CPT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer, density-operator

Consider the following channel:
$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \lambda\rho^T + \frac{1-\lambda}{d}I $

Which $\rho^T$ means transpose and $d$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space.

My question is, for what values of $\lambda$ This map is CPT? (Completely positive Trace preserving map)

Comment: Hi, this looks like a homework question, are you stuck at a particular point?

Comment: @user2723984 thanks for answering, yes that a homework but that seems impossible to solve, It seems Choi matrix is not suitable to solve it in an arbitrary dimension, and also solving from the definition of CPT is not straightforward, I'm really stuck at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove something more general: let $\mathcal T$ be a not completely positive map. For which $\lambda$ is the map

$$ \mathcal E(\rho)=\lambda\mathcal T(\rho)+\frac{1-\lambda}{d}\mathrm {Tr}(\rho)I$$
completely positive? Notice that this is just the convex combination of the channels $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal D$, where $\mathcal D$ is the completely depolarizing channel, $\mathcal D(\rho)=\frac{1}{d}\mathrm {Tr}(\rho)I$. I added the $\mathrm {Tr}(\rho)$ to ensure linearity, of course it doesn't matter for states.

Consider the Choi operator of $\mathcal E$

$$ C_{\mathcal E}=\lambda C_{\mathcal T}+(1-\lambda) C_{\mathcal D}$$

$ C_\mathcal D=I\otimes \mathcal D(|\Omega\rangle\langle \Omega|)$ has a very simple form, i.e.

$$ C_\mathcal{D}=\frac{1}{d}I\otimes I$$

This means that if $\psi$ is an eigenvalue of $C_\mathcal T$, $\lambda\psi+\frac{1-\lambda}{d}$ is an eigenvalue of $C_\mathcal E$. For $\mathcal E$ to be completely positive we need all of its eigenvalues to be positive. If $\psi$ is positive so is $\lambda\psi+\frac{1-\lambda}{d}$, if $\psi$ is negative then we need

$$ \lambda <\frac{1}{1 -d\psi}=\frac{1}{1+d|\psi|}$$

since the one of the left hand side is a decreasing function, this must be true for the smallest eigenvalue $\psi$ (i.e. the negative eigenvalue with the largest absolute value), let's call it $\psi_m$, hence we need

$$ \lambda<\frac{1}{1+d|\psi_m|}$$

You can now compute what this value is for the transpose map, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. That was very easy and I was stuck at hard methods

Comment: A key point which should be stressed is that it is an *if and only if*: $\mathcal E$ is CP *if and only if* the Choi state is positive. This is since we can also go back from a positive Choi state to a CP map using the reverse part of the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism.